# Printing out an array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am having trouble trying to create an array then printing the first 10 elements from the array... this is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
    char term[200][40];
    FILE *ifp;
    int i;
    ifp = fopen("terms.txt", "r");

    if (ifp == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file...\n");
    }

    fgets(term, 40, ifp);

    for(i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    printf("%s", term[i-1]);
    }
}
```

Also, compiler gives me an error: "note: expected 'char * **restrict**' but argument is of type 'char (*)[40]'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char term[200][40];
```

is an array of 200 string buffers that are capable to hold 40 characters.

```
fgets(term, 40, ifp);
```

tries to read a string from file and store it to buffer that first argument points to (expecting `char*`).

Try to read it the following way:

```
int i = 0;
while (fgets(&term[i++][0], 40, ifp);
```

`fgets` will return `NULL` on failure making it stop.

Answer (score 1):

```
fgets(term, 40, ifp); //THIS IS WRONG
```

Modify for loop and remove above statement

```
for(i = 1; i < 11 && fgets(term[i-1], 40, ifp)!=NULL ;i++) {
printf("%s", term[i-1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `term` as any array, when passed to function, is treated as pointer to its first element.
And the first element of term is...array of 40 chars, so you pass

`char (*)[40]`

to `fgets`, and it expects

`char *`

. 
By the way, your compiler told you exactly the same thing earlier than me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 fgets(term, 40, ifp);

        for(i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        printf("%s", term[i-1]);
        }
```

in the piece of code above you read one string from `ifp` and store it in `term` but then you try to read 10 strings and since term isn't initialized you don't know what would be printed